# How to understand the iptables rules with docker mapping port

Tags: docker, iptables

### Scene

- Run a container

```sh
docker run --dit --name mynginx -p 7070:80 nginx
```

the mynginx container get an IP 172.17.0.9

- The Automatically added rules

```sh
iptables-save |grep 172.17.0.9

...
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.9/32 -d 172.17.0.9/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.9:80
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.9/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
...
```

### How to understand this rule

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.9/32 -d 172.17.0.9/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

source and destination are the same in this rule,
which case does it work.